# c# mysql вставить координаты google Earth в базу данных

Tags: c#

помогите пожалуйста разобраться, есть приложение на winforms, нужно подключить google Earth и вставлять в базу данных координаты. чтобы после по этим координатам можно было перейти , просто взять и вставить координаты в базу данных не получается, какой тип данных нужно выбрать чтоб вставить координаты . помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Я не уверен, но [вот это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinate?view=netframework-4.8) может как-то Вам помочь

Comment: библиотеку описывает , насчет как сохранить геолокацию в базу данных не можете подсказать ?

Comment: Создайте колонки БД типа `[Latitude]`, `[Altitude]` итд, колонки которые описывают конкретную точку координаты google Earth. После того как получите конкретную координату, то просто преобразуйте её в `GeoCoordinate` т.к в конструктор подаются `double` значения

Comment: дело в том что , пользователь сам через форму вводит определенную координату через google earth.  mysql не понимает этот синтаксис, то ли я должен преобразовать ее в  GeoCoordinate, после чтобы увидеть это дело в datagride мне обратно нужно преобразовать ?

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос нажав "править" и там покажите что принимает google earth а что на форме у вас и что у вас в бд